# I got confused with logic used in this program, need in-depth explanation

Tags: java

```
public class Prime
{    
 public static void main(String args[]){    
  int i,m=0,flag=0;      
  int n=3;//it is the number to be checked    
  m=n/2;      
  if(n==0||n==1){  
   System.out.print(n+" is not prime number");      
  }
else
{  
   for(i=2;i<=m;i++)//Why are we using m here?
{      
    if(n%i==0){      
     System.out.print(n+" is not prime number");      
     flag=1;      
     break;      
    }      
   }      
   if(flag==0)  { System.out.print(n+" is prime number"); }  
  }//end of else  
}    
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding, why are we using this logic? [for(i=2;i<=m;i++)] what is the role of 'm' here?

Comment: Did you try to debug in your IDEs or did you write some System.out.println statement for the value m ?

Comment: Well, instead of using n/2 they've declared a variable called 'm'
We know that a divisor of a number can't be superior to half the number itself, so if N is big enough we'll just be wasting resources for nothing if we go beyong N/2 without finding a divisor (or 2 divisors)

Comment: Using `m` as a limit to check. Like @Noblesse said, you only need to check until `n/2`. If you find another more efficient way, you can change m without affecting `for`loop. In this case, for prime numbers, `m = sqrt(n)` is the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay attention to this line:

```
m = n / 2
```

`m` is used in the `for` loop to limit the quantity of iterations done. The previous statement means that the loop will go from 2 to the half of the value of n.. This is done in order to "optimize" the execution time of this algorithm because the divisors of a number over its half are not meant to be covered.

This is not the best optimization for this algorithm. A better approach would be to limit the `for` loop until the square root of n:

```
m = (int)Math.sqrt(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `n` is your potential-prime-number. 
Variable `m` is set to `m = n / 2;`.

Then you iterate `i` from `2` to `m` and check if you can divide your potentially-prime-number by `i` (without the rest).

If you can divide - it is not a prime number, because prime numbers are dividing only by itself and by `1`.

[You have to check only numbers from `2` to `n / 2` to be sure that the potentially-prime-number is a prime number or is not (you have here the reduction of quantity of necessary iterations).]